Passport - small damage on passport
I currently have a small damage on the corner of my passport cover and biometric page (see attached image). I don't know if JP embassy will accept it since I am meant to travel there within a few weeks and I already have an approved visa. I also already verified that the NFC chip still works fine.




It should be fine, since the damage is purely cosmetic, looks like wear & tear, and does not affect the biometric data page or any visa stamps etc.
See also: Damaged passport travelling to Japan
